# Python subprocess output format?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I wanted to print the OS system information for a Pi in python.
The OS command "cat /etc/os-release" works fine in the Terminal with nice row formatting.

In Python I used :

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output("cat /etc/os-release", shell=True)
print("Version info: ",output)
```

That works, but I do not get any newlines:

```
Version info:  b'PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"\nNAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"\nVERSION_ID="9"\nVERSION="9 (stretch)"\nID=raspbian\nID_LIKE=debian\nHOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"\nSUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"\nBUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"\n'
```

How can I format the output to add newlines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert bytes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: 'str(output)' would work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that your string is a bytestring, as denoted in the output with the letter **b** as a prefix to the string:
Version info:  **b**'PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux...

A simple fix would be to decode the string as follows:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output("cat /etc/os-release", shell=True)
output = output.decode("utf-8")
print("Version info: ",output)
```

And the result will be printed correctly. You can verify that this is a different object if you print its type before and after decoding:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output("cat /etc/os-release", shell=True)
print(type(output))
output = output.decode("utf-8")
print(type(output))
```

This will result in the following output:

```
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: That did it !Nice clean solution !